# Is it possible to get infected by malware from running a foreign Xcode project?

Tags: malware, ios, xcode

An entrepreneur hired me to build out his mobile app and passed me the Xcode project files. From what I've read and heard about the development agency that built out his beta they're sketchy to say the least. The word SCAM was thrown around plenty of times, and he made it pretty clear his experience with them was dismal at best.

Now I want to run the app, check for bugs; make sure at least the app is copacetic, but I'm uncertain of whether or not I'm opening myself up to vulnerabilities running this foreign project on my machine. Can anyone shed any light on the matter?

Comment: I would be _very_ surprised if running a foreign Xcode project did not open the risk of code execution.

Answer (score 1):

> If you run un-trusted code on your box ... it is no longer your box

That being said, if you do a full backup of your Mac and [Airgap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(networking)) it before running the code.  Then wipe it, and reinstall from backup before connecting it to anything ... you should be ok (as long as a rootkit isnt injected into the firmware which is low probability but still a risk).

Short of that, I would read through every line of code and verify the integrity of any/all third party libs the code is using before running it ... and even then I would step through the entire thing.

IMO if this `entrepreneur` is willing to buy you a new computer to test the code on ... I would say go for it.  However, judging by his decision to hire this other group to write the beta code (aka cheapest outsource work he could find) ... I doubt he is paying you enough to take the risk with your own computer.

Comment: You could use a virtual machine, no?

Comment: @forest theoretically possible but I have had nothing but bad experiences in attempting to run Mac in a VM and getting Xcode to work.  Unless something has drastically changed since I last attempted it ... it is an effort in futility at best.

Comment: Oh that's a shame. Yet another reason I don't use OSX.

Comment: I've been successful in getting a Mac to run in a VM. The performance was unacceptable, but can I use this as a means of vetting the code on the VM before using it on my personal Mac?

Comment: @shoe I too have been able to get Mac running in a VM ... the problem was always getting Mac + Xcode running in the VM.  If you can get it up and running ... yes it would be a safe viable option for testing.  I wish you the best (I personally have never had much luck getting both to work).

Comment: I had the unfortunate experience of learning iOS development on a Mac VM. Which is why I'd like to get in and get out. Any quicker way of validating the safety of running the project than scanning it line by line, knowing I can run it in a VM?

Comment: @shoe Not the best solution, but you could maybe go to a local library (if they have Macs) or Apple Store and try running it, assuming your contract would allow it.

Comment: @Steve Right, but how will running it on one computer be any more revealing than running it on another. On what basis will I be able to determine after running it that the machine was not owned?